Why did I got CrashLoopBackOff for one pod and the other is working fine?
I have deployment,that has error that is coming over the time.
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
pod/picanagm-solution-5cb8887968-qk4pr   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   140 (78s ago)   11h
pod/picanagm-solution-77f5fcfdc-kwd9w    1/1     Running            0               2d20h

logs of the failed pod
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  2m42s (x3258 over 11h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container

and
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dlogging.config=/app/run/logback.xml -DcontentServer.factory-reset=folder -DcontentServer.factory-reset.folder-name=file:/app/bookmarks -DSameSite=none -Dconfiguration.sign-off.enabled=true -Ddata.extraction.templates.base.dir.path=${java.io.tmpdir} --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://10.244.4.81:8778/jolokia/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/activeviam/MINDZ/starter/main/MINDZApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)

One replicaset is ok,the other is not ready
replicaset.apps/picanagm-solution-5cb8887968   1         1         0       11h

Why?
How to debug this behaviour?

This question is similar to: How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Turing85 nO,because one pod is working fine.

You seem to misunderstand. It seems that the one pod crashing is executing a code path the other pods do not. The core issue is that the program is running the wrong JVM version. I suggest updating the JVM.

@Turing85 ok,so it is purely developer issue?

No. It seems to be one of the following - a plugin compiled with the wrong target version, or - a wrong jre version in the image used. The former is an issue for whoever controls the compile process. The latter is an issue for whoever controls the image building process

ok,see the pipeline,I agree. But why is other pod doing fine? the same deployment.

Wait a second... you have two repliasets... what is the diff between the two sets?

yes,the first one is 1         1         1 (D,C,R),the second  1         1         0.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The answer for this question Why did I got CrashLoopBackOff for one pod and the other is working fine? is:

When the older one works well, it means there are no issues. However, when the new one isn't functioning properly, it indicates that there is an error with it. In a deployment with two replicas, the older one waits for the new one to be ready and will eventually go down on its own. So, if the new one isn't working correctly (CrashLoopBackOff), the older one will still be up and running.

